# Bootstrap split button dropdowns not displaying properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have not override any class of the Bootstrap and I have all the css and js.

When ever I paste the same code of the bootstrap then also it display not properly code is as follow:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Action</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <span class="caret"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
     </button>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Display this type of wrong output

[image]

Comment: Surely this is a copy/paste error? -> `class="btn btn-primar![enter image description here][1]y"`

Comment: ohh sorry this is mistake when write question note in my codding i have edited my question

Comment: have you changed any of the default css on `button`s or `.btn`s like `padding`?

Comment: no i have clarify that thing in my question

Comment: i thinks you can also try this in you page you will got same output

Comment: @user3363563 this is with default css and your html only http://jsfiddle.net/mru45/ and looks correct

Comment: yes this is display properly i don't know why not in my page i have try this in 3 pc on other projects not giving output proper

Comment: can you provide us with a live example of your code? or can you edit the above jsfiddle to include your other css and html

Comment: i got where is actual problem?

it is in class="caret" don't know but it has problem with property display=inline-block in this class

Comment: do you use font awesome? Maybe you try it with its caret?

Comment: is this resolved? You should answer and accept your own question if so, so it falls off the "unanswered" page...

Comment: yes this is resolved by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the doctype you are defining in your page.
Try setting it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Action</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding:9px">
         <span class="caret"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
     </button>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

kinda a css hack, but worked for me nontheless.